# This only works on nice whole numbers

Tags: perl

Small program that give a percent of how far it is in counting to X number:

```
$total = 10000;
$up = 0;
print "$up%\n";
$up = 10;
while ($line_c != $total){
    if (($line_c/$total) == ($up/100)) {
        print "$up%\n";
        $up += 10;
    }
    $line_c++;
}
print "$up%\nDone";
```

The problem is though, it only likes whole numbers. 
If you do 10001, it will not print anything...

Comment: I think you suffer from _comparing floating point numbers_. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/21587663/5830574, for example.

Comment: @PerlDuck that's different; infinite precision would make that work.  Here, it's more of a logic flaw: no integer divided by 10001 will ever equal 10/100.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare integers instead, the floating point numbers can be different:

```
int($line_c / $total) == int($up / 100)
```

But it seems you have the logic wrong. It prints the output for the first 10 lines, and then does nothing for the rest of the loop (same with 10000). Verify by printing $line_c together with $up.